# Sending Email Using Acumatica REST API

Tags: c#, .net, acumatica

I am trying to send a mail from Acumatica RestAPI by using the below
API URL:

```
https:/{url}/entity/Default/17.200.001/Email?CompanyID=STS&ScreenID=CR306015
```

The problem am facing while calling this API with the request shown here:

```
{
    "From":
            {
            "value":"abc.service@abc.com"
            },

            "To":
            {
                "value":"example@abc.com"
            },
            "Subject":
            {
                "value":"Test Email"
            },
            "Body":
            {
                "value":"Sample Erp Bot Mail Check"
            }

    }
```

Is the mail is getting saved into Drafts rather than saving into sent(not being sent to receipt).

The response I am getting when calling the RestAPI is:

(Response from Postman Status:200 OK)

```
 "MailStatus": {
        "value": "Draft"
    }
```

Please suggest a way to send email through Acumatica [RestAPI] using C# and .NET.

Comment: did you check if the email is queued to be processed ? see CO409070

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to actually perform 2 API calls:

1. Create email (as you do right now)
2. Execute send action.

To execute Send action you do the following request:

```
POST: https://{url}/entity/Default/17.200.001/Email/SendEmail
Body: 
{
  "entity":
   {
     "id": "put yor email ID here that you get as a result of email creation"
   }
}
```

For optimization purpose you can combine both requests into one like that:

```
POST: https://{url}/entity/Default/17.200.001/Email/SendEmail
Body: 
{
  "entity":
   {
     {
        "From":
        {
        "value":"abc.service@abc.com"
        },

        "To":
        {
            "value":"example@abc.com"
        },
        "Subject":
        {
            "value":"Test Email"
        },
        "Body":
        {
            "value":"Sample Erp Bot Mail Check"
        }
    }  
  }
}
```